# Page with centered content shifted by width of scroll bar

Tags: html, css, layout, scrollbar

I like to assign web pages a **fixed width** with a **centered layout** for better compatibility. The problem however is, that once a **scroll bar** appears, the entire content is shifted to the left by half of the width of the scroll bar.

This can be particularly annoying when the user switches between pages that do and don't have vertical scroll bars. In that case, the content is not always on the same position in the middle.

**Question:** Is there a best practice for this so that the page won't wiggle left/right when browsing?

HTML

```
<div id="content">
    page content, 400px width and centered<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    once scroll bars appear<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    content is shifted left by the width of the scroll bar<br /><br /><br /><br />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#content
{
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

See: [jsFiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/htLjvrz9/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically the only work around is to make it so that the scrollbars are always there and you do this like this in your CSS:

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Great and simple solution!